# Pandas sum and max across axis 1 in new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have df below:

```
  Hour                                      1     2    
    CU0111-012379-H Output Energy, (Wh/h)   2.0  3.0    
                    Lights (Wh)             4.0  5.0  
                    Lights+Media (Wh)       0.0  0.0    
                    Total Usage (h)         0.0  2.0     
                    Lights (h)              0.0  1.0   
                    Light+Media (h)         0.0   0.0    
                    Battery Voltage, (V)   13.5  13.7     
                    Max Watt, W             7.5   4.5
```

and I have added a Total Column at the end:

```
col_list= list(df)
df['Total'] = df[col_list].sum(axis=1)

  Hour                                      1     2   Total 
    CU0111-012379-H Output Energy, (Wh/h)   2.0  3.0   5.0  
                    Lights (Wh)             4.0  5.0   9.0
                    Lights+Media (Wh)       0.0  0.0   0.0  
                    Total Usage (h)         0.0  2.0   2.0   
                    Lights (h)              0.0  1.0   1.0 
                    Light+Media (h)         0.0   0.0  0.0   
                    Battery Voltage, (V)   13.5  13.7  27.2   
                    Max Watt, W             7.5   4.5  12.0
```

However. I would like to get the max value across axis 1, not the sum, in the total column for:

```
 Battery Voltage, (V)      
 Max Watt, W
```

Such that df will be:

```
  Hour                                      1     2   Total/Max 
    CU0111-012379-H Output Energy, (Wh/h)   2.0  3.0   5.0  
                    Lights (Wh)             4.0  5.0   9.0
                    Lights+Media (Wh)       0.0  0.0   0.0  
                    Total Usage (h)         0.0  2.0   2.0   
                    Lights (h)              0.0  1.0   1.0 
                    Light+Media (h)         0.0   0.0  0.0   
                    Battery Voltage, (V)   13.5  13.7  13.7 <-max  
                    Max Watt, W             7.5   4.5  7.5  <-max
```

a diabolical beginners attempt might look like this  :

```
df3['Total/Max'] = d3[col_list].sum(axis=1).df3.groupby(level=1).df3['Battery Voltage, (v)'].transform(max)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) and [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for check if level has some values and then `max` and `sum`:

```
L = ['Battery Voltage, (V)','Max Watt, W']

print (df.index.get_level_values(1).isin(L))
[False False False False False False  True  True]

df['Total/Max'] = np.where(df.index.get_level_values(1).isin(L),
                           df.max(axis=1), 
                           df.sum(axis=1))

print (df)
                                          1     2  Total/Max
Hour                                                        
CU0111-012379-H Output Energy, (Wh/h)   2.0   3.0        5.0
                Lights (Wh)             4.0   5.0        9.0
                Lights+Media (Wh)       0.0   0.0        0.0
                Total Usage (h)         0.0   2.0        2.0
                Lights (h)              0.0   1.0        1.0
                Light+Media (h)         0.0   0.0        0.0
                Battery Voltage, (V)   13.5  13.7       13.7
                Max Watt, W             7.5   4.5        7.5
```

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting by `mask` and apply `max` and `sum`, also need `~` for inverting `boolean array`:

```
L = ['Battery Voltage, (V)','Max Watt, W']

mask = df.index.get_level_values(1).isin(L)

df.loc[mask, 'Total/Max'] = df[mask].max(axis=1)
df.loc[~mask, 'Total/Max'] = df[~mask].sum(axis=1)
print (df)
                                          1     2  Total/Max
Hour                                                        
CU0111-012379-H Output Energy, (Wh/h)   2.0   3.0        5.0
                Lights (Wh)             4.0   5.0        9.0
                Lights+Media (Wh)       0.0   0.0        0.0
                Total Usage (h)         0.0   2.0        2.0
                Lights (h)              0.0   1.0        1.0
                Light+Media (h)         0.0   0.0        0.0
                Battery Voltage, (V)   13.5  13.7       13.7
                Max Watt, W             7.5   4.5        7.5
```

EDIT by comment: Need double `numpy.where` with another mask.

```
L = ['Battery Voltage, (V)','Max Watt, W']
mask1 = df.index.get_level_values(1).isin(L)
mask2 = df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'Lights (h)'

df['Total/Max/Min'] = np.where(mask1, df.max(axis=1),
                      np.where(mask2, df.min(axis=1), df.sum(axis=1)))

print (df)
                                          1     2  Total/Max/Min
Hour                                                            
CU0111-012379-H Output Energy, (Wh/h)   2.0   3.0            5.0
                Lights (Wh)             4.0   5.0            9.0
                Lights+Media (Wh)       0.0   0.0            0.0
                Total Usage (h)         0.0   2.0            2.0
                Lights (h)              0.0   1.0            0.0
                Light+Media (h)         0.0   0.0            0.0
                Battery Voltage, (V)   13.5  13.7           13.7
                Max Watt, W             7.5   4.5            7.5
```

Comment: to further complicate things, I also need to get a minimum figure for this row: `Lights (h)`,  in the `total/max` column. What would you suggest?  I've tried to adjust your `mask` and `np.where` but either ignores or says too many arguments...